# Python get number sequence from a string with a index

Tags: python, string

I want to get a number sequence from a string.

So I have string(folder_name) => "FGH SN_234256 aalhflsh"

with .find() I can find out where to start.

```
     search_fave_phrase = fave_phrase.find("SN_")

     print(search_fave_phrase)
     #Output 4
```

Now I want the whole number after the SN_. But if there is a whitespace or letter the number should stop. My goal is to get that number,
no matter where it is in the string.

Comment: Regex is an option: `import re; re.findall(r"SN_(\d+)", fave_phrase)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex:

```
import re

text = "FGH SN_234256 aalhflsh"

pattern = r'SN_([0-9]+)'

print(re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=text)[0]) # (It's still a string so you might need to convert to int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression.

```
import re

fave_phrase = "FGH SN_234256 aalhflsh"
match = re.search("SN_([0-9]+)", fave_phrase)
print(match.group(1))
```

Explanation: It looks for "SN_" followed by numbers. `group(0)` would be "SN_234256" and `group(1)` is the part in brackets, i.e. "234256".